# Send ID and name to Database using php, mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I want to input only name from form but ID and name both will be sent to database using php. Please assist.

Comment: You have provided zero code so we can only guess. If you are editing an existing item, the ID is often carried in the Query String, so you can use that in a form, or a hidden HTML input field.

Answer (score 0):

When creating the database,You need to use ID as primary key and set the value as auto incremented.Then you don't need to insert ID through from it will take ID automatically.